# Dropdownlist, postback on all selections

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm wondering if it is possible, using an asp:dropdownlist if you can fire a postback on every selection, even if it is the same?  For example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_SortCars" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SortCars">
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Volvo" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Saab"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Audi"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So rather than having a 'OnSelectedindexChanged' event you would have a IndexSelected event.  The reason?  Well, if somebody selects a volvo, and this would be a list of models (or something), if they selected volvo again it would show the same list but in reverse order!  At the moment I can only get the list to fire if they change an index.

So basically can you force a postback on selection, any selection?

Comment: may i know, what is the purpose for having a postback on every selection. Usually this selectedindexchanged worked with the scenarios i dealt with so far.

Comment: How about coming up of two different DropDownList controls: one for the list of brands and the other one for the list of models based from the selected brand?

Comment: It was just an example, but no one list, a-z, select again z-a.